# Calculate formula for the results of density function given specific input range

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Since my original question seems to be formulated wrong (I thought there would be a general method to solve that kind of exercise), I'll try to clarify with a specific exercise:

Given a two-dimensional absolutely continuous random vector with density function fxy(x,y) =

1 if 0 < x < 1 and x < y < x + 1

0 otherwise

and the fact that X is an absolutely continuous random variable with density function fx(x) =

1 if 0 < x < 1

0 otherwise

The exercise is then:

Let fy(y) denote the density function for Y. Calculate fy(y) for 1 < y < 2.

So what I was doing at first was to define fy(y) as the integral of fxy(x,y) dx. Now I have to find a formula for fy(y) for 1 < y < 2.

I know the answer is 2 - y, which I can also see if I for example insert som random values between 1 and 2 into the density function fy(y) and then compare these results with the inputs. But what would be the correct way to calculate this, 2 - y?

Thanks.

Comment: If you already have formula for $f_X(x)$ then for $x$ from the specific interval it give you the values of density function directly. Say, if $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ for } x < 0\\ 3e^{-3x} & \text{ for } x\geq 0\end{cases}$$ then $f_X(x)=3e^{-3x}$ for $x\in(1,2)$, and $f_X(x)=0$ for $x\in(-2,-1)$, and $f_X(x)=3e^{-3x}$ for $x\in(9,12)$, and so on.

Comment: Maybe I formulated my question wrong then. What I'm given is actually a joint density function fxy(x,y) and then I'm supposed to calculate a formula for, lets say, fx(x) for 0 < x < 1. Therefore I start by defining fx(x) which is just the integrale of fxy(x,y) with dy. But by defining it this way, I don't really get the formulas. So I thought there would be a specific way to calculate a formula as needed

Comment: It will be better to edit your question. Nothing in the question pointed to a joint distribution, integration and so on. Sure, the density $f_X(x)$ is the integral of joint density function over all $y$. Show concrete example where you face difficulties, and we can help you.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a [picture with  you region](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RegionPlot%5Bx%20%3C%20y%20%26%26%20y%20%3C%201%20%2B%20x%20%26%26%200%20%3C%20x%20%26%26%20x%20%3C%201,%20%7Bx,%200,%201%7D,%20%7By,%200,%202%7D%5D) and consider some $y\in(1,2)$. For this $y$ you should integrate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1$ in horisontal direction inside blue area: from $x=y-1$ to $x=1$:
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{y-1}^1 1\, dx = 1-(y-1)=2-y.
$$

[image: Area with joint density equals 1]

If you want to find $f_Y(y)$ for $y\in(0,1)$ you should integrate by $x$ from $x=0$ to $x=y$:

$$
f_Y(y)=\int_0^y 1\, dx = y.
$$